# Can a filter access properties from my BaseController?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, action-filter

I have a basecontroller that has a property like:

```
public class BaseController : Controller 
{
    public User CurrentUser {get;set;}

    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // if session cookie found, set User object here
    }
}
```

Now I want to create an action filer that I could set on controllers or actions that I want to do something like:

```
if (User.IsAdmin) 
{
} 
else 
{
    // redirect to login or some page 
}
```

So this filter `@AdminOnly` I could put on a controller or action and this will ensure that only users who have the IsAdmin flag set will be able to view the action.

Does a filter have visibility into the currently executing controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you use

```
if (filterContext.Controller is BaseController)
{
    BaseController ctr = (BaseController)filterContext.Controller;
    if (ctr.User.IsAdmin)
    {....}
}
```

[Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionexecutingcontext%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)

Comment: The filter will fire after the base controller correct?

Comment: No, the action filter will fire before the controller onexecuting but Authorization runs before action executing. Try the above code in your action filter and in your base controller you could override  OnAuthorization instead of OnActionExecuting.

Comment: @publicstatic Which onActionExecuting gets called first when you breakpoint them? I would've thought filter would get called before your base controller, before you had a change to set the User.