# How can ActionFilterAttribute access a protected int? from BaseController?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a base controller which sole purpose is to get an `int` value from `HttpContext.Session` and make it available to all inheriting controllers.

Now I'm trying to redirect to the login view when said value is not set and the user tries to access a restricted view without being logged in.

This is what I've got so far:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected int? BranchId
    {
        get { return (HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("BranchId") as int?); }
        set {}
    }

    public BaseController() {}
}

public class RedirectingActionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        if (BranchId < 1) // BUT BranchId DOES NOT EXIST IN THIS CONTEXT
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
            {
                controller = "Home",
                action = "Login"
            }));
        }
    }
}

public class EmployeesController : BaseController
{
    private readonly VaktlisteContext db;
    private readonly IMapper auto;

    public EmployeesController(VaktlisteContext context, IMapper mapper)
    {
        db = context;
        auto = mapper;
    }

    [RedirectingAction]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        Branch branch = await db.Branches.Include(e => e.Employees)
            .Where(b => b.Id == BranchId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        if (branch == null) return NotFound();
        BranchViewModel vm = auto.Map<BranchViewModel>(branch);
        return View(vm);
    }
}
```

I have read [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26023954/can-a-filter-access-properties-from-my-basecontroller), but wasn't able to work out how the solution could be applicable in my case.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `HttpContext.Session` you can access this in the attribute code too by doing `HttpContext.Current.Session`. You don't need access to controller for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not access to `BranchId` attribute on `RedirectingActionAttribute` class directly because it is member of `BaseController` class.
try this code:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

    if ((filterContext.Controller as BaseController).BranchId < 1) 
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
        {
            controller = "Home",
            action = "Login"
        }));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Protected prop is protected, when you defined a property as protected access then you can not expect to access it in derived class!!.

But about accessing property in action

```
public class ValidateActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var controller = filterContext.Controller as BaseController ; 
        if (controller == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("It is not EmployeesController!");
        } 
        var propVal= controller.PropertyName;  
        //check propVal here
    }
}
```

but you can also use `Session` like `context.HttpContext.Session` in `ActionFilter`